# Internal proxy for external system

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch

I have a web server in a Kubernetes `Deployment` which uses an ElasticSearch instance on ElasticCloud.

I have parameterised (thanks to environment variables) my container, from a `Secret`, with this kind of url: `https://elastic:***@xxx.yyy.eu-west-3.aws.elastic-cloud.com:9243`

I'm really dissatisfied for these reason:

- My container have access to the credentials
- I have downtimes whenever I change the password

Is there a kind of `Service`, or any good practise, which would be able to proxy ElasticCloud (adding credentials)? If it is possible, I'd like to have a mechanism to update credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a Deployment of `caddy:2` Pods which a Caddyfile mounted from a Secret, something like this:

```
http://elastic-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local:9243 {
    reverse_proxy https://xxx.yyy.eu-west-3.aws.elastic-cloud.com:9243 {
        header_up Authorization "Basic Zm9vOmJhcgo="
        header_up Host {upstream_hostport}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
    }
}
```

The create a Service named `elastic-proxy` in the namespace (`default` in this example). Point the app Pods to this service instead of the Elastic Cloud.

Explanation:

This will create a Caddy 2 server which reverse proxies everything coming to port 9243 with virtual host `elastic-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local` to the Elastic Cloud and adds an `Authorization` header with the Basic Auth credentials (foo:bar here).

You can create the password with `base64` like this:

```
$ echo 'elastic:password' | base64
ZWxhc3RpYzpwYXNzd29yZAo=
```

Every time you change the password (why do you even change it?), just modify the Caddyfile in the Secret.